# Reopen request (What kind of weapon would you need...)

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question was closed as too broad:

[What kind of weapon would you need to level an entire city to glass?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98051/what-kind-of-weapon-would-you-need-to-level-an-entire-city-to-glass)

I'm not seeing how it was too broad.  It seems answerable, even if the answer is -- as several comments suggest -- "you can't".  Someone out there might be able to think of a weapon which could do what OP wants, either some reasonable extrapolation of Earth weaponry, or something from another story.

Answer (score 6):

That question asks these questions:

1. Is this possible? **Unlimited access to minerals, I presume**
2. What kind of weapon could effectively "gooify" entire cities? **Is that a word?**
3. Is this new goo layer can be used for metal work?
4. What is the quality of this goo layer?
5. How would a civilization with near medieval technology utilize this layer?
6. What kind of effect this weapon would have on environment?
7. What would be the condition of "new earth" after global usage of this weapon?

As you can see, each of these questions should be asked in different posts. I must also ask the OP what he means by "gooify". And then, why there is "glass" in the title of the question.

As of current revision, this question cannot be reopened. It is too broad (multiple questions) and unclear.

Comment: I took the "goo" to be the pool of metal underneath where the city used to be.  So yes, there are several questions, but are you suggesting that we can auto-hold any question which has more than one question mark in it?

Comment: @akaioi I don't suggest auto-hold a post with more than 1 question mark. Each post must be handled separately. Each post must have only 1 **main** question. Other questions should only explains what the main question ask. For example: *How to make artificial moon? Is it feasible with current earth technology?"

Comment: Hmm ... then for this Q perhaps we can suggest it be split into two, because there are basically 2 different questions.  One being, what kind of weaps could cause such damage.  The other being, could a low-tech civ profitably mine what's basically a congealed pool of metal.  Maybe a third dealing with environmental damage.  ?

Comment: @akaioi yes. If it is split to a series of questions, then we can answer the questions.

Comment: A'ight I'll go see if I can convince OP to do this...

Comment: @akaioi you can point out that his profile still shows “unregistered” too.

Comment: Re split up: **sandbox** !